# Spring Boot REST API won't convert JSON to object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I'm running into a failure, but I can't figure out why. For a simple test, I want to quickly create a RESTful API to accept a JSON and convert it to an object (POJO).

Restcontroller:

```java
@RestController
public class RESTController {

    @Autowired
    AuthorService authorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/setsAuthor", headers = "Accept=application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addAuthor(@RequestBody Author author){
        authorService.addAuthor(author);
    }

}
```

Data object:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String authorName;
}
```

Service:

```java
@Service
public class AuthorService {

    @Autowired
    AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        try {
            authorRepository.save(author);
        } catch (IllegalAccessError e) {
            System.out.println("cant save Author: " + author + " to Respository");
        }
    }
```

Repository interface:

```java
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
}
```

Post Request at

```
http://localhost:8080/setsAuthor
```

With JSON:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "authorName": "SomeAuthor"
}
```

I also tried to wrap the Items in the JSON in a `"Author" :{}`

The RestController won't map my JSON to the object. It always says id = null, authorName = null when I debug the program.

What am I doing wrong? I remember it always worked this way.

Comment: Do not use Entities at controller level. read about 3tier architecture. Add Getter and Setter to your entity.

Comment: I added Getter and Setters and it worked. Normally i wouldnt use it that way. I just want to test some other things and needed a working DB connection. But i keep that in mind for other Projects. Thank you :-)

Comment: A POJO should have getters and setters beside the default constructor. (So other services can instantiate it and set properties)
You can add them directly or using Lombok annotations (`@Data`, or `@Getter` and `@Setter`)

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Getter` and `@Setter` to entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Author {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
```

instead of `@Setter`